# How to simply kill python-tensorflow process and release memory?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Whenever I run a python script that uses tensorflow and for some reason decide to kill it before it finishes, there is the problem that ctrl-c doesn't work. I would use ctrl-z but it doesn't release the gpu memory, so when i try to re-run the script there is no memory left. Is there a solution for this in linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In bash find the process id (PID) of the process of your python script with the top command.

```
top
```

For example the PID is 5000

Exit top. Then kill the process:

```
kill 5000
```

Answer (score 3):

I always start tensorflow programs from script. For instance:

```
python tf_run.py 1> ./log 2> ./err &
```

Then use top/htop to monitor your program status. In case there are many other progresses on your machine, top only the python progresses.

```
top -p $(pgrep -d',' python)
```

Finally, when you want to kill the progress,

```
ps aux | grep tf_run.py | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9
```

This command line is extremely useful when you there are multiple tensor flow progresses.

Answer (score 3):

Don't run this on your desktop, but for HPC/remote machines with no display, this kills all left over GPU-using processes:

`nvidia-smi -q -d PIDS | grep -P "Process ID +: [0-9]+" | grep -Po "[0-9]+" | xargs kill -9`

Answer (score 0):

run `top` command to find the process id. then `kill` it.

as:

```
top
```

find the pid

```
kill pid
```